# Strange error in this SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I found the following stored procedure from [here](http://mkramar.blogspot.com/2011/05/hit-highlight-for-sqlserver-full-text_5118.html), while creating this stored procedure in my database, I get this error message: (I'm running SQL Server 2008 Developer)

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure HighLightSearch, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Here is the full Stored Procedure code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HighLightSearch](@contents NVARCHAR(MAX), @searchTerm NVARCHAR(4000), @style NVARCHAR(4000), @maxLen INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c NCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @len INT = 0
    DECLARE @l INT = 0
    DECLARE @p INT = 0
    DECLARE @prevPos INT = 0
    DECLARE @margin INT
    DECLARE @term NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @retval NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    DECLARE @positions TABLE
    (
        S INT,
        L INT
    )

    -- find all occurances of the search term

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(N'FORMSOF(FREETEXT, "' + @searchTerm + '")', 1033, 0, 1)

    OPEN cur1
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @term

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        WHILE 1 = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @p = CHARINDEX(@term, @contents, @p)
            IF @p <= 0 BREAK

            SET @l = LEN(@term)

            IF @p > 0 BEGIN
                SET @c = SUBSTRING(@contents, @p - 1, 1)
                IF @c <> ' ' AND @c <> NCHAR(9) AND @c <> NCHAR(13) AND @c <> NCHAR(10) BREAK
            END

            INSERT INTO @positions (S, L) VALUES(@p, @l)
            SET @p = @p + LEN(@term)
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @term  
    END  

    CLOSE cur1
    DEALLOCATE cur1

    -- build the result string

    DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT S, MAX(L)
    FROM @positions
    GROUP BY S
    ORDER BY S

    SET @margin = LOG(@maxLen) * 5
    IF @margin > @maxLen / 4 SET @margin = @maxLen / 4
    SELECT @prevPos = MIN(S) - @margin FROM @positions

    OPEN cur2
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @p, @l

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @len < @maxLen
    BEGIN
        SET @retval = @retval + SUBSTRING(@contents, @prevPos, @p - @prevPos)
        SET @retval = @retval + '<span style="' + @style + '">' + SUBSTRING(@contents, @p, @l)  + '</span>'
        SET @len = @len + @p - @prevPos + @l
        SET @prevPos = @p + @l

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @p, @l
    END  

    CLOSE cur2
    DEALLOCATE cur2

    SET @margin = LOG(@maxLen) * 5
    IF @margin + @len < @maxLen SET @margin = @maxLen - @len
    IF @margin > 0 SET @retval = @retval + SUBSTRING(@contents, @prevPos, @l)

    RETURN '...' + @retval + '...'
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @var=N'FORMSOF(FREETEXT, "' + @searchTerm + '")'
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@var, 1033, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I've seen, that `@searchTerm` is declared with a size of 4000, so please replace in my snippet `DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(4000)`